# How to create a pivot table with value ranges in the index and headers and values in the frame?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

This is my input data
[image: 1]

**And the output I want**:

```
PAX range     DELHI PUNE MUMBAI
0-50           56    22   56
51-100         55    33   77
101-150        52    27   89
```

Comment: Welcome, please provide more detail about how you get to your result... are you counting rows from the `numberofguests` columns? Also please provide your data as text, and even if it is a callable line as returned by `df.head(20).to_dict('list')`

Comment: I want to count the phone numbers in the PAX range for different cities.

Comment: I have used till now this:
bins=[0,50,51,100,101,150]
lms_leads['PAX'].value_counts(bins=bins, sort=False)
But this only returns the  overall count but I want it city wise!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are not clear from your question:

- There is no `PAX` column in the dataframe, perhaps there are more columns not shown, in which case it is all right.
- I'm assuming by your comment that the aggregation function you want to use is count of rows.

If this is all correct then you can binarize and pass to a groupby call with.

```
output = df.groupby([
    pd.cut(df.PAX, bins=[0, 50, 100, 150]), 'City'
    ]).size().unstack()
```

Comment: Sorry my bad its PPP column not PAX and I want to count unique phone numbers in different PPP range for different cities.